# How to use python-colormath's Delta E function with pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, colors

I am using python-colormath in order to calculate the color difference delta E 2000 between a list of Lab colors.

I have two pandas dataframe (df1 and df2), in each dataframe I recorded the Lab values.

here is my code:

```
L1 = df1.L
a1 = df1.a
b1 = df1.b

L2 = df2.L
a2 = df2.a
b2 = df2.b

colors1 = LabColor(lab_l= L1, lab_a = a1, lab_b = b1)
colors2 = LabColor(lab_l= L2, lab_a = a2, lab_b = b2)

delta_e_76 = delta_e_cie1976(colors1, colors2)

>> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Is there a way to convert pandas series into a LabColor class object?

Comment: colormath tries to coerce the input to LabColors to floats ([`self.lab_l = float(lab_l)`](https://github.com/gtaylor/python-colormath/blob/master/colormath/color_objects.py#L304))

Comment: Do you want to use Delta E 2000 or 1976? You say 2000 but your code uses 1976.

Comment: Thank you for your Michael, that helps me a lot ! I want to used both actually, in order to compare the difference between the 2 equations (1974 and 2000). Following your ideas of using colour library, i have tried it and it worked !! :)

Comment: Great! Happy to help. If you found one of the answers useful please don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `python-colormath` does not support the use of anything that can't be converted to a `float` as input to its `LabColor` objects.

If you want to keep using `python-colormath` you could loop over the series objects instead of using the function directly on it.

```
delta_e_76 = []
for L1, a1, b1, L2, a2, b2 in zip(df1.L, df1.a, df1.b, df2.L, df2.a, df2.b):
    colors1 = LabColor(lab_l= L1, lab_a = a1, lab_b = b1)
    colors2 = LabColor(lab_l= L2, lab_a = a2, lab_b = b2)
    delta_e_76.append(delta_e_cie1976(colors1, colors2))
```

Alternatively, you could try to wrap the setup and call to `delta_e_cie1976` and wrap it using numpy's `vectorize` function.

```
@np.vectorize
def delta_e_vectorized(L1, a1, b1, L2, a2, b2):
    colors1 = LabColor(lab_l=L1, lab_a=a1, lab_b=b1)
    colors2 = LabColor(lab_l=L2, lab_a=a2, lab_b=b2)
    return delta_e_cie1976(colors1, colors2)

delta_e_76 = delta_e_vectorized(df1.L, df1.a, df1.b, df2.L, df2.a, df2.b)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `python-colormath` does not support the use of anything that can't be converted to a `float` as input to its `LabColor` objects.

To keep the advantage of vectorized computations you might want to look at using a different library that supports this kind of operation, e.g., [Colour](http://colour-science.org/).

(Disclaimer, I am involved in this project)

Using `colour` you could do this to compute the color differences:

```
from colour import delta_E_CIE1976, tstack

delta_e_76 = delta_E_CIE1976(tstack([df1.L, df1.a, df1.b]),
                             tstack([df2.L, df2.a, df2.b]),
                             )
```